# Java counterpart of ASP.NET data access tutorials

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, mysql, jakarta-ee

I am relatively new in Java technologies.  I want to know the best frameworks and which to consider when I am making a similar web application just like in the [ASP.NET Data Access Tutorials](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/data).  My backend is MySQL.  And my criteria from being 'similar' is ease of use and application extensibility and maintainability.

Comment: why tag asp.net and c# if you need Java tutorials

Comment: hey aaron, i'm looking for a similarity in asp.net/learn

Comment: sorry Aaron Digulla that would be Saurabh.  My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might also want to take a look at [Hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Look for "JPA" (Java Persistence API). There are lots of tutorials, especially when you try to add a UI to your app. JPA itself is explained [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbpz.html).

[EDIT] As [Fredrik Wallenius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/473596/fredrik-wallenius) pointed out: Try [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html).

Comment: JPA is nice. Imho, though, Oracle's tutorials are a bit too complex. Might want to take a look a this tutorial: http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html